# PIE.htc and jquery watermark conflict

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Ive got input type password. Thats why I used watermark plugin to set ther readable value password.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Then I applied PIE.htc to have round corners on my input.

effect is that sometimes after watermark is executed input dissapears. It happens 1/10 times.

But If I set timeout for example 1 s end then run watermark input dissapears everytime.

I think that there must by some kind of race

Does anyone have any idea how to solve that problem

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would forget about the pie.htc altogether on this particular piece, or do like Chris Pratt said and look for a different plugin.

Honestly, in my opinion if your users are still using an outdated browser it isn't worth the extra trouble trying to get something as trivial as rounded corners to work. It won't effect the functionality, and they'll probably never notice.

I generally just throw CSS Pie on sites when I'm done just to give it an added "oomph" but if it's this much trouble, I'd just forget it.

I know that doesn't answer your question, but it's just some personal advice.

Good luck!

Comment: link is in the question. I dont have sample to show :( When I dont use PIE.htc to make round corners input doesnt hide after execution of watermark plugin. It only happens when input is type password

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I must have totally missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't technically have a solution, but I can at least frame your problem:

In order to create placeholder text for a password field (without the placeholder attribute in HTML5), plugins like this create a new input with type text and lay it on top of the password input. Of course, this involves absolute positioning and z-indexing.

Then, in order to create rounded corners in IE, CSSPIE actually creates its own additional VML elements that it adds to the DOM, and also uses absolute position and z-indexing to create the effect of rounded corners.

The problem here is obviously that the two separate plugins messing with the same element's position and z-index are conflicting with each other. It's not so much a race condition as plain-and-simple incompatibility. You might want to try a different placeholder text plugin and see if it doesn't conflict.